# sending local data to web browser... how?

Tags: ssl, websocket

I have a deployed SSL website displaying maps.

I have a local application (flight simulator) which spits out location data.

I'd like to have the browser's map update itself based on location data. Not just for me, but *anyone* running this local application should be able to see *their* location on *their* browser.

1. websockets won't work because the webapp is SSL & one cannot connect localhost or 127.0.0.1 with SSL websocket and insecure websockets are blocked. (Using DNS tricks and deploying certificates won't work because it should support "anyone".)
2. Using javascript File API with a UNIX domain socket won't work because, while I believe javascript can read domain sockets, there's no way for a User Browser to 'select' a domain socket as a File object.

The only pathway I see is by having the local application pass data directly to my webserver & have the webserver forward it to the appropriate browser. (Say, when local application is started, user provides their webapp login & the webserver will be able to pair incoming location data with user's web session.)

Is there another way? (a different path, or different configuration to permit websocket?) Seems too bad that localhost doesn't get a free pass with respect to security.

[image]

Comment: WeSockets don't require SSL. If it's a local app, you can use WebSockets without SSL... just don't allow external connections (you can do this when defining the listening socket). **or** have 2 listening sockets map to the same application, one with using SSL (open to the world) and one unencrypted (limited to localhost).

Comment: From my testing, if browser is loading a secure page, all the websockets also need to be secure, even if the websocket is to localhost. You're seeing something different?

Comment: you’re right... but why do you need a secure connection to localhost? Why not use unencrypted HTTP when the data is limited to the same machine?

Comment: The website itself needs to be secure (user must login, etc.) All javascript and ajax calls are secure (they're not sourcing from localhost). Only this one datafeed is localhost & I don't care if it's secure (or if it's websocket or http, for that matter). But, for the browser on my machine to include data from a websocket or XHR from my machine, the browser insists that source be secure (because the page is secure.)

Comment: IMHO: It would be easier to design an SPA on localhost that loads remote resources securely (via localhost proxy or directly) then trying the other way around.

Comment: "SPA" is special purpose app? That's a lot of work & imposes larger installation requirement on each enduser (plus managing future updates). It only took a couple hours to implement the UDP-WSS interface (blue line). Plus it'll work for non-localhost (say, an ipad, sitting next to the flight sim.)

Comment: SPA is a Single Page Application. But you’re right, if everything is already coded, you might prefer using a reverse proxy, so most HTTP requests to localhost are routed to the remote HTTPS website (except the WebSockets and local data requests).

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'll keep non-proxy interface for now, but if look to alternative if performance becomes an issue.